# How do i move my track from trackmania to trackmania exchange

Tags: trackmania-forever

i can't find a way to download my track and put it on track mania exchange can anybody help me. I've tried looking in all menus but there is nothing about downloading.

Answer (score 1):

You need to upload the track file, that is a .gbx file. Here is a reddit thread about how to find them: https://www.reddit.com/r/TrackMania/comments/ey84e7/i_cant_figure_out_how_to_install_maps_tm_united/

- Open the TMUF Launcher
- Click "Help"
- Click "Custom Data"
- Under "Go to directory" click "Challenges"

It'll open the folder where you can save track files (*.Challenge.Gbx)

Once you're in-game you'll find your downloaded tracks by going into "Play Solo" and then "Browse".

If you own TM United Forever, you can play tracks from any of the TMX sites. But primarily you'll be grabbing maps from:
https://united.tm-exchange.com/
and
https://tmnforever.tm-exchange.com/